# Let $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^4$. Determine the polynomial $p_2$ of degree less than or equal to 2 such that $||f-p_2||_2$ is minimal

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

also compute $||f-p_2||_2$. Write $p_2$ with respect to $\{P_0,P_1,P_2\}$ and $\{1,x,x^2\}$

I know its helpful to show what I have so far but I really don't know where to start. I'm looking at examples and they all give you a $g(x)$ so I'm kind of confused. I just need any direction to help get me going. Thanks!

Comment: Is $p_2$ supposed to be of degree $\leq 2$?

Comment: What are $P_0, P_1, P_2$? Beyond that, you know that a degree-two polynomial (in whatever basis you choose) has three parameters (e.g., in the monomial basis it's just $ax^2+bx+c$ for some $a,b,c$); try writing out the $L_2$ norm of your difference explicitly in terms of $a,b,c$ and see if you can minimize that.

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed as follows:

First of all, consider $\Vert f - p_2 \Vert_{L^2(-1,1)}^2$ instead.
Then, replace $p_2(x)$ with $a + bx + cx^2$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.
You obtain
$$\int_{-1}^1 (f(x) -a -bx -cx^2)^2 dx\,.$$
Expanding the integrand, you can find a matrix $M$ so that
$$\Vert f - p_2 \Vert_{L^2(-1,1)}^2 = (a\ b\ c) M \left( \begin{align}a\\b\\c\end{align} \right)\,.$$
If the matrix is $M$ symmetric positive definite, then ...
(this is up to you).